# PHP MSSQL 5.5.8-1 on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, centos

On my CentOS 6.5 server I've configured a LEMP server with PHP 5.5.8-1 installed from Remi repository.

I need to instal php-mssql but when I try to install it:

```
yum instal --enablerepo=remi php-mssql
```

it says I need **`php-pdo-5.4.27-1.el6.remi.x86_64`** but I have installed **`php-pdo-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64`**

I think this means that the Remi repository has **`php-mssql-5.4.27-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm`** and I need **`php-mssql-5.5.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm`**.

Am I right? If yes where can I find this `rpm`? I've found it only for [Fedora 14](ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/remi/fedora/14/remi/x86_64/php-mssql-5.5.8-1.fc14.remi.x86_64.rpm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize it's an older post but i successfully installed using

```
yum -y --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-mssql
```